# how to download files from tomcat server

Tags: java, android

I am using Eclipse. So I have `BOOKS` folder under `WEb-INF`. I want to download the files through my Android application. So how do I give the Url path? I have given: `"http://adaptive:8080/BOOKS/pdftest.pdf"`.

But it is giving `filenotFoundException`. So what should the url be?

Comment: There's likely another path component in there "http://adaptive:8080/<something>/BOOKS/pdftest.pdf" depending on how you've deployed your application.

Comment: and file needs to be in public web space or you can write a servlet which will serve for your files which aren't directly publicly accessible using some security constraint or somethin

Answer (score 5):

Folders beneath *WEB-INF* are not visible to web clients. If you want *BOOKS* to be accessible you should move it up so that it resides in the same folder as *WEB-INF*.

Answer (score 0):

give the url like http://adaptive:8080/SerachWeb/BOOKS/profession.pdf. SerachWeb is the name of my web application. Now I can download through  tomcat server to my android application.